# Show that $\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \sqrt[k]k-1$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \sqrt[k]k-1$ diverges.

I was advised to investigate the proof of $\sqrt[k]k \rightarrow 1$ to get inspiration. If this is true, why does the sum not converge to $0$?

Comment: Not every sequence converging to $0$ has a finite sum. Consider $\frac{1}{k}$, for example.

Comment: You can split it up into the the sums of two sequences, one of which is divergent since it diverges to negative infinity, and the other which converges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^K\left(k^{1/k}-1\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^K\left(e^{\frac1k\log(k)}-1\right)\\\\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^K\frac{\log(k)}{k}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{k=2}^K \frac{1}{k}
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ diverges, the series of interest diverges by comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Show that

$$k^{1/k}-1 \sim \frac{\log{k}}{k} $$

for large values of $k$.  Compare the series then to the harmonic series, which diverges.